# Proximity sensor black screen

Tags: swift, proximitysensor

I enable the proximity in the application and when user keep long "tap" over the senzor and the screen became dark.

```
     //MARK:- Activate Proximity Sensor
func activateProximitySensor() {
    let device = UIDevice.current
    device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(proximityStateDidChange), name:UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: device)        
}

@objc func proximityStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    if viewModel.dataSourceArrayCarousel.count > 0 {            
        currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.currentPage, section: 0)
        let model  = viewModel.getModelFotCellAtIndexPathForCarousel(index: currentIndexPath.row)
        let cell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: currentIndexPath)

        revealCard(model: model, cell: cell as! MyCardCell, indexPath: currentIndexPath)
    } }
```

Any suggestions about how to manage these kind of situations ?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to prevent the screen from dimming when proximity monitoring is active and the sensor is covered. You are not supposed to use the sensor for anything else than preventing accidental ear touches.